# J2ME Game Builder - additional sprite sequence

Tags: netbeans, java-me, sprite

I'm using Netbeans Game Builder and creating there animated sprite. I would like to add more sequences (walking down or jumping).

I've searched many tutorials and everyone says it should be done by 'create function' from a pop up menu. But I still cannot find it. Which pop up menu do they mean?

Comment: Just right click on the sequence which is automaticly generated and pop-up will appear.